# Weird deformities when remeshing and using the grab brush

Tags: mesh, sculpting

[image][image]Using grab brush but instead of moving as one smooth mesh, it is chunky and drastically raised in some parts despite just doing a minor adjustment. I used the voxel remesher at .02 and have a mirror modifier and have the setting use deform only on to run a bit faster. Not sure what is relevant. How do I get rid of these weird deformities? Smooth them out doesn't fix it. I tried remeshing again but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Had clipping enabled in Mirror modifier. Unchecked that and now it is fixed.